# How to finish current view / activity in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Is there any method similar to `this.finish()` in android to finish current flutter activity.

Comment: Look at my answer, is it what you are looking for? :)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Do you mean close current screen and come back to previous screen? 
If that, *Navigator.pop(context)* should do the work. However, if you are at the entry screen (the first screen of the app and this screen has no parent screen/previous screen), Navigator.pop(context) will return you to a black screen. In this case, we have to use *SystemNavigator.pop()*.

**But don't use SystemNavigator.pop() for iOS, Apple says that the application should not exit itself :)**

Below code will work on Android for both cases

```dart
if (Navigator.canPop(context)) {
  Navigator.pop(context);
} else {
  SystemNavigator.pop();
}
```

Comment: @Jayesh Can you give me more detail?

Comment: I got the solution view this so post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50929083/how-to-navigate-from-one-screen-to-another-start-activity-and-close-current-sc/50929609#50929609

Comment: This works for me thanks. But can you provide a solution for iOS instead of just saying don't exit ?

Comment: Hi, Apple will not approve us to exit the app. As all iOS apps you may use, you can not exit it from the app.

Answer (score 44):

use `Navigator.pushReplacement(BuildContext context, Route<T> newRoute)` to open a new route which replace the current route of the navigator

Comment: this is not working in flutter 2.2... atleast in my code? 
The activity closes but the data done on the activity remains constant

Answer (score 2):

use thie code

```
 Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                                return AddDemoUnitActivity();
                              }));
```