# How to navigate from one screen to another (start activity) and close current screen (finish) in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I am beginner to Flutter.

I have splash screen and I can navigate from splash to login screen, but I can't destroy the splash screen.

I want to finish the splash screen after I navigate to login screen just like below action in android, how can I achieve this in Flutter.

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, Login.class));
finish();
```

Thanks.

Comment: https://flutter.io/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics/

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: I have already refer that link, but can't get idea how finish the splash screen, when I press back button in android it always opens splash again, and I need splash only once.

Comment: How do you show the splash screen? You might need `popAndPushNamed`, `pushNamedAndRemoveUntil`, or `pushReplacmentNamed` to show the first screen after the splash screen to make the new screen the top route.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use MaterialPageRoute to create route to your widget. Then place your route along with context to Navigator.
pushReplacement finishes current screen while push creates new widget over it.

```
Route route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => YourWidget());
Navigator.pushReplacement(context, route);
```